# Check if an array contains Date, that is between Two Dates in the second array

Tags: javascript

I have two arrays.

```
let dateArray = ['2018-05-04T00:00:00+01:00', '2019-04-20T00:00:00+01:00', '2020-05-29T00:00:00+01:00'];

let rangesArray = [['2021-09-01','2022-09-01'],['2019-09-01','2020-09-01']];
```

How to check if the dates from dateArray are between the dates in rangesArray.

rangesArray[0] is first range - Im interested in dates between 2021-09-01 and 2022-09-01.

rangesArray[1] is second range - Im interested in dates between 2019-09-01 and 2020-09-01.

Comment: Those are not dates - they are strings. Step 1: create dates.

Comment: @RandyCasburn is right. Create dates using **new Date()**. You can also set a specific format for your date. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way :

```js
let dateArray = ['2018-05-04T00:00:00+01:00', '2019-04-20T00:00:00+01:00', '2020-05-29T00:00:00+01:00'];

let rangesArray = [['2021-09-01','2022-09-01'],['2019-09-01','2020-09-01']];

const res = []
dateArray.forEach(d => {
  rangesArray.forEach(a => {
    if ((new Date(d) >= new Date(a[0])) && (new Date(d) <= new Date(a[1]))){
      res.push({date: d, range: a[0] + ' ' + a[1]})
    }
  })
})

console.log(res)
```

Comment: In your if statement, you are using `... >= ...  && ... <= ...`. I think it's a mistake, because the date cant be equal to the beginning and the end of the range in the same time. It should be  `>= && <`  or `> && <=`.

Comment: Hi mate :) date don't need to be equal, it can be (smaller OR equal) and  (bigger OR equal)

Comment: Hi :) You are absolutely right !

Answer (score 1):

use `Date.parse()` to convert string to date for comparison.

working example:

```js
function dateCheck(from, to, check) {
  var fDate, lDate, cDate;
  fDate = Date.parse(from);
  lDate = Date.parse(to);
  cDate = Date.parse(check);

  if (cDate <= lDate && cDate >= fDate) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

let dateArray = [
  "2018-05-04T00:00:00+01:00",
  "2019-04-20T00:00:00+01:00",
  "2020-05-29T00:00:00+01:00",
];

let rangesArray = [
  ["2021-09-01", "2022-09-01"],
  ["2019-09-01", "2020-09-01"],
];

for (let i = 0; i < dateArray.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < rangesArray.length; j++) {
    console.log(dateCheck(rangesArray[j][0], rangesArray[j][1], dateArray[i]));
  }
}
```

**explanation:**
`dateCheck` function checks if the date is between `from` date and `to` date. with two loops you can get the result that you want.